# How can I redirect a servlet to two another servlets using two buttons?

Tags: java, servlets, redirect

I want to know how is it possible to redirect a servlet to two other servlets by clicking two buttons.

Comment: What is meant by **redirect a servlet to two other servlets** !!!

Comment: Do you mean redirecting or forwarding a request/response pair from one servlet to another?

Comment: Yes I mean connecting to the next page. It means simply after clicking that button I want the expected servlet to appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax calls.

OR

Use two forms for button with two action parameters each mapping to a servlet.

And then on click of the button, submit the required form using javascript

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in multiple ways 
 1. You can use the Ajax request 
 2. You can submit the form to a common class and get the submitted button name redirect from 
there to he respective
 3. You can have multiple forms for multiple buttons

Answer (score 1):

If you meant that your *form action* stays the same (say, *ActionServlet*) but you need to redirect to two different servlets (say, *TargetServlet1*, *TargetServlet2*) based on which button is clicked just give your *submit* buttons different names as follows.

```
<form action="ActionServlet">
    <input type="text" name="user" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="target1" value="Goto 1" />
    <input type="submit" name="target2" value="Goto 2" />
</form>
```

Then if the user clicks on `Goto 1` you can test it by the presence of `target1` as a request attribute

```
/ActionServlet?user=john&target1=Goto+1 // first button clicked
/ActionServlet?user=jane&target2=Goto+2 // second button clicked
```

in the query string (or, POST parameters depending on your *form*'s *method* attribute) and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With Ajax from jQuery

2 Servlets 1 button

```
    $('#button1').click(function() {    
           $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "Servlet1",
            data: { tusvariables: tuvalor,
                    tusvariables1: tuvalor1
                  },
            success: function(data) {
                        if(data.true){
                                $.ajax({
                                 dataType: "json",
                                 type: "POST",
                                  url: "Servlet2",
                                  data: { tusvariables: tuvalor,
                                          tusvariables1: tuvalor1
                                        },
                                  success: function(data) {
                                      alert("Pase el 2 Servlet")
                                  }
                                });
                          }
                    }
              });
      });
```

Or separate

```
           $('#button1').click(function() { 
           $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "Servlet1",
            data: { tusvariables: tuvalor,
                    tusvariables1: tuvalor1
                  },
            success: function(data) {

                    }
              });
      });
```

Saludos! \(0.0)/

Comment: This is good. But I wanted a simple code. But its ok. This is good.